# How to reset Kate default color schemes?

Tags: kde, colors, editors, kate

I accidentally changed some of [Kate](http://kate-editor.org/)'s default color schemes. How do I set them back to default? I tried reinstalling (including with the option to remove config files) but it kept my changes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The file you need to remove, or edit if you prefer, is:
`kateschemearc`, which is usually located in a folder like `$HOME/.config/` (the name of your .kde file may be .kde4 or something similar).

Remove that file and all default colour schemes are restored.

Comment: That file doesn't exist. There is no `~/.kde`, and `~/.kde4/share/config` has no `kateschemarc`, so anything starting with `kate`. Where else should I look?

Comment: How about a find command:  find ~ -type f -iname "*katesche*rc*"

Comment: I found it in both `~/.kde4` and `~/.kde`, and deleted both. That fixed it.

Comment: I found none of these files throughout my whole home. I deleted `~/.kde/share/config/katerc` but to no avail. Actually, the file was `~/.config/kateschemarc`, note the missing e. For finding it use this instead: `find ~ -type f -name "katesche*"`